# Struggling with inflate algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, inflate

I'm having a difficult time understanding how the inflate algorithm works even after reading the RFC and reviewing c and javascript implementations.  I compressed a file with the text "TestingTesting" and got the following result in hex:  0B 49 2D 2E C9 CC 4B 0F 81 50 00

I tried reading the data after 16 and 32-bit endian swaps but after reading the first 3 bits I can't get any further because the next 5 bits don't make sense.  What am I doing wrong and how can this be parsed?

References I've used:
RFC 1951
[Javascript](https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate/blob/master/rawinflate.js)
[C](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gnuzip/gnuzip-12/gzip/inflate.c)

Comment: Please post your code so we can actually help you. We can't read minds (yet), so it will be hard to tell where the issue is without an example.

Comment: I haven't written any code yet because I'm still trying to understand how to parse the bits correctly.  After I understand the algorithm, the coding and verification will be much easier. I was hoping someone could help me break down and parse the bits in the example for the first few codes.

Comment: How are your "reading the data after 16 and 32-bit endian swaps" and getting "after reading the first 3 bits I can't get any further because the next 5 bits don't make sense"?

Comment: Parsing it by hand. Eg: 0B 49 = 0000 1011 0100 1001, swap the bytes for endian conversion, then read the first bit which is a 0 (not last block), next 2 bits = 10 (static table), then next 5 bits = 01001 which is supposed to be the number of literal codes 257 but that doesn't make sense for the sample text file I used: "TestingTesting"

Comment: Ok so how about posting a few links in your original question to the inflate algorithm and implementations you've reviewed. I'm not familiar enough with it to do it by hand off the top of my head.

Comment: [RFC 1951](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt)
[Javascript](https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate/blob/master/rawinflate.js)
[C](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gnuzip/gnuzip-12/gzip/inflate.c)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The output from the compressor is a stream of bytes.  Why are you doing an endian swap?

Looking at the first few bytes, as binary:

```
0B  = 00001011
49  = 01001001
2D  = 00101101  
2E  = 00101110
...
```

From section 3.1.1 in the RFC:

- bits are read from right to left, so the first bit of the header, `BFINAL`, is `1`:

  ```
   00001011
          ^
  ```
- numbers are packed LSB first, and we read from right-to-left, so `BTYPE` is `01`:

  ```
   00001011
        ^^
  ```
- That's the fixed Huffman code block type, so we expect a Huffman code next.  Huffman codes are packed MSB first, so the first code is `10000100` (we continue on to the next byte here):

  ```
   00001011
   ^^^^^
   01001001
        ^^^
  ```
- Looking at the table in section 3.2.6, `00110000` to `10111111` represent literal bytes 0 - 143, so `10000100` (= `0x84`) is the literal value `0x54`, which is the ASCII code for "`T`".
- Continuing, the next code is `10010101` (= `0x95`) which is literal value `0x65` which is "`e`".

...and so on.

Comment: +1 for a concise and legible answer - it took me half-a-dozen reads of RFC1951 to properly grok what you've summarised in four bulletpoints here.